# scanf won't let me leave loop — any idea why and how to fix it?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
int main() {
  char one[50]; char two[50];
  while (scanf("%10s %10s",one,two) == 2){
    printf("%s %s\n",one,two);
  }
}
```

The function won't let me leave the loop

```
Charanas-MacBook-Pro:Testing zone Charana$ ./a.out
first second 
first second
one two
one two
one 
two
one two


leave
```

Any idea how to fix this so that I can leave the `scanf` when I go to a new line, or only enter one word into terminal, not two?

Comment: `scanf` does not know about line breaks. It will keep scanning until it has found two words, no matter across how many lines they are spread. If you want to have real line-based input, use `fgets` or non-standard modules like `getline` to read a line, then scan that line.

Comment: Or use end-of-file like `Ctrl-Z` (Windows console) or `Ctrl-D` (Linux).

Comment: @M Oehm `scanf()` does "know" about like breaks - ti depends on the specifier..  If anything, `scanf("%s...` does not distinguish line breaks from spaces.  Agree best to use ``fgets()/getline()`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) function skips white space before reading a string via `%s`.  Newlines are white space.  Therefore, it continues reading until it gets the second string.  Similarly with numbers; if you ask for two numbers, `scanf()` won't stop reading until it gets two numbers, or it comes across a character that can't be a part of a number — it reads across newlines quite happily.

If you want line-based input, do not use `scanf()`; use the [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) from standard C or 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) from POSIX, coupled with
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  Then you can get sane behaviour.

As it stands, the `scanf()` function is working exactly as it is intended to work; it won't complete until it has a second string.  You can interrupt the program, but that's usually not what you want.  You can signal EOF (e.g. by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> on Unix-like platforms or <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> on Windows), but that can lead to further problems — you have to clear the EOF condition before you can get further input, for example.

Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` has many advantages — go with it.